# Data is not showing after getting from JSON

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to get data from server. Data is coming. Here what i am doing

```
 $.ajax({

     url: "EventCalendar_Review",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {

         console.log(data);
         var a = data.eventTitle;
         var b = data.fromDate;
         var c = data.toDate;
         var d = data.url;

     }, //end of success

     complete: function(request, textStatus) {
         var req = request;
         var status = textStatus;            
     } //end of complete

}); //end of .ajax
```

data variable has its data in JSON format something like this

```
[object{ eventId=1, eventTitle="Khan to hold maide", fromDate="2012-03-06", toDate= "2012-03-07" more...}, Object { eventId=2, eventTitle="India tie not about revenge", fromDate="2012-03-06", more..}, ...]
```

Data is printing in the console. But when i am using just below console.log(data)

```
console.log(data);
var a = data.eventTitle;
var b = data.fromDate;
var c = data.toDate;
var d = data.url;
```

Then i am getting a, b, c and d undefined. a sholud get value of eventTitle(Khan to hold maide) and so on. Why i am getting undefined?

Thanks

Comment: JSON uses colon delimiters between values, not equal signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the *something like* makes it a valid JSON object (http://jsonlint.com), then you've got an array of objects:

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var thisOne = data[i];

    var a = thisOne.eventTitle;
    var b = thisOne.fromDate;
    var c = thisOne.toDate;
    var d = thisOne.url;

    // do something with these variables.
}
```

If you just want the first object, you can use `data[0]` to access it:

```
var a = data[0].eventTitle;
var b = data[0].fromDate;
var c = data[0].toDate;
var d = data[0].url;
```

Comment: @EvilP @JustinEthier Yes you all are right. I was doing wrong. But now i did in this way and i got the values:). `$.each(data, function(index, event){abc.push({title: event.eventTitle,start: event.fromDate,end: event.toDate, url: event.url});              });  Thanks to you all :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting an array back. What if you try accessing your data by index:

```
var a = data[0].eventTitle;
var b = data[0].fromDate;
var c = data[0].toDate;
var d = data[0].url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your JSON is invalid !
JSON does not use `=` it uses `:` !!

`"key":"value"` instead of `"key"="value"`
Seems like you are also not receiving and JSON Object from your server.
 You are receiving an array of objects !!

Comment: you are right.  JSON uses key:value. Actually i am using google API to convert my data to JSON format, may be that is why i ma getting data in the `"key"="value"` format. It is JSON, that's why i mention my dataType JSON `dataType: "json`